# Rep League and Recent Activity weeks don't match?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-leagues, stackexchange.com

I think the Recent Activity is on a Sunday start day but the Rep Leagues are on a Monday start day.

Goto your **Recent Activity** page and hit **this week**, the date range given (a this moment) is `2010-08-22 00:00:00Z to 2010-08-24 23:59:59Z` - or basically Sunday to "now" (end of today).

If I do this on SU, it currently shows that I've earned 85 this week and 509 last week.
But, on the rep leagues this morning, I'm showing 30 for this week and 563 for last week.

30, is what the recent activity pages claims I earnt yesterday, and it what makes me think the rep leagues must be starting from Monday.

I have earnt 0 this morning, so that shouldn't be causing any issues.

<strike>Can someone verify that these are different and/or if it's intentional?</strike>

### Update

I've just noticed that this week's rep league has the title `Week of Aug 23, 2010` - which *kind of* gives it away that they start a week on a Monday.

In which case, *should* the two match?

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if the question actually included a link to the rep league?

Comment: @cyberkiwi, a fair point, but any specific link would have been out of date in days, let alone the months since this went up. The general link is http://stackexchange.com/leagues for anyone who's not aware.

Answer (score 1):

Rep League is apparently calculating reps directly from actual votes, instead of reading from the denormalized rep table, which may include some extra reps from deleted posts.

It should be consistent with the result from the [rep report](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation).

Comment: OK, well on my SU rep report I still only got 30 yesterday (==Rep League). I did get 85 yesterday+today(==Activity Page) (I had mistyped this in my question as 80, now corrected). I got 564 for the last Mon-Sun (==Rep League) and 509 for the Last Sun-Sat week (==Activity page). So there no real differences there from what I've already posted.

Comment: Whoops - 564 for last Mon-Sun *doesn't* match the 563 for the Rep Leauge. I guess there's an extra/deleted down vote in there as well..

Comment: @DMA: Rep league scores are synced only at the end of the day. The reps gained today won't be counted until tomorrow.

Comment: I have no rep gains today, so this is not a factor. And I have stated this in my question already.